# Searching for Value Using Key in HashMap in Haskell

Tags: haskell, hashmap, roman-numerals

I am trying to create a simple program which converts any given char number 1-9 to its roman equivalent. I figured I could store the value pairs in a map (ex. `[('1', "I"), ('2', "II"), ...]`

Given this, how do I look through a map in Haskell?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what sort of map you're using? Are you using a library?

Comment: Simply have a LIst like `(romanNums = fromList([('1', "I"), ('2', "II"), ... , ("9", 'IX'))` I then want to pass the char number so ex '1' as a parameter to my function and retrieve the corresponding roman number

Comment: What is fromList?

Comment: @user253751: likely imported from https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.6/docs/Data-Map-Internal.html#v:fromList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an association list you can use the [`lookup`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:lookup) function from `Prelude` to get a value out of the list. For example

```hs
list :: [(Char, String)]
list = [('1', "I"), ('2', "II")]

val = lookup '1' list -- Just "I"
```